The moduli space of marked K3 surfaces has at most two connected components
I'm reading Huybrechts' Lectures on K3 surfaces and I'm actually stuck on Proposition 7.5.4, stating that

Let $X$ be a K3 surface. If $\operatorname{O}(H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}))/\operatorname{Mon}(X)$ is generated by $-\operatorname{id}$, then the moduli space $N$ of marked K3 surfaces has at most two connected components.

The proof starts pretty standard. Picking two markings $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ on $X$, their difference $\varphi_1^{-1}\circ \varphi_2$ is an orthogonal transformation, so that we may suppose $\psi = \pm \varphi_1^{-1}\circ \varphi_2$ for some $\psi \in \operatorname{Mon}(X)$. So we now have to prove that $(X,\varphi_1)$ and $(X,\varphi_1\circ \psi)$ are in the same connected component of $N$. Let's suppose $\psi$ is $\in \operatorname{Im}(\pi_1(S,t) \rightarrow \operatorname{O}(H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})))$ for some smooth family $\mathcal{X} \rightarrow S$. I quote the following part, that I don't understand.

The local system $R^2\pi_*\mathbb{Z}$ can be trivialized locally, i.e. identified with $\underline{H}^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$. The monodromy $\psi$ is then obtained by following these trivializations along a closed path in $S$ beginning in $t \in S$. The classifying map to $N$ necessarily stay in the same connected component.

Now, I think I got the part describing the construction of $\psi$ via gluing local trivialization (I guess it's the standard way to build the monodromy representation of $\pi_1(S,t)$) but I have no idea about what he means by "classifying maps". I never heard this notation before and I don't know how this observation concludes the argument.
Any tip is welcome.

The classifying map is the map $S\to N$, induced by the family $\mathcal X\to S$.
